# .NET Docking a control to another control

Tags: vb.net, controls, docking

It is not possible to dock one control to another one, is it?

For example, if you have the option

```
"Hide application after" "(COMBOBOX)" "minutes"
```

in your application...

"Hide application after" is one label, then comes a combobox that lets the user select a decimal value, then comes the "minutes" label.

I find it a bit hard to set the sizes of these 3 items correctly. 
However, e. g. Thunderbird manages these well. I was wondering if I have to fallback on custom coding in VB.NET, or if there is an automatic way to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Old Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: @LarsTech -- Just curious; why not put that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FlowLayoutPanel control to house the three controls and allow them read from one control to the other:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnLoad(e)

  flp.WrapContents = False
  flp.Controls.Add(New Label() With {.Text = "Hide Application After",
                                     .AutoSize = True,
                                     .Margin = New Padding(0, 6, 0, 0)})
  Dim cb As New ComboBox
  cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
  cb.Items.AddRange(New Object() {10, 20, 30})
  cb.Width = 42
  cb.SelectedIndex = 1
  flp.Controls.Add(cb)

  flp.Controls.Add(New Label() With {.Text = "Minutes",
                                     .AutoSize = True,
                                     .Margin = New Padding(0, 6, 0, 0)})
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow, are really great answer. Especially the beauty of the Margin is really great. On my system, I would prefer New Padding(0, 8, 0, 0), but I guess that really depends on the system.